# Style Issue On Buttons for Upload/Delete

Tags: html, css, button

http://jsfiddle.net/qtt3W/

I put my problem into the jsfiddle here. Basically what my goal is, is to have the Delete button lay to the right of the Upload button.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your upload button a left float css style.

```
<input type="submit" style="float: left;" name="submit" value="Upload">
```

Comment: i dont have enough rep to up it but that fixed it perfect...its always the little things i miss! thanks a lot